# Why would a tower change target from a hero to creeps?

Tags: dota-2

In some games there were cases when a tower was attacking a hero, and the hero would stop attacking and face a creep that's nearby, the tower would change target and start attacking the creep.

How to do this? Or is that a bug?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Towers have a rather specific ruleset for determining who they're going to attack, as noted in http://dota2.gamepedia.com/Aggro.

They basically attack (in order):

- An enemy unit or hero attacking a friendly hero with auto attack
- Same attacking the tower with auto attack
- Same attacking any friendly unit with auto attack
- Closest enemy unit
- Closest enemy hero
- Closest enemy siege creep

The tower will switch to a new target if:

- The tower can't attack it's current target (i.e., it runs away or is killed)
- If an enemy hero or unit attacks a friendly hero
- If an enemy hero currently targeted by the tower manually selects another enemy unit (so, the enemy hero currently being targeted targets one of *their* allies)

In those cases the tower will check the first list again for a new target, so what might have happened is the enemy hero selected one of their allies to attack to force the tower to switch  to someone else.

Comment: That last one could use some additional explaining.. You mean simply clicking on an allied hero causes the tower to re-determine its target? or do I actually have to have control of the hero like in the case of a disconnected player, or a shared control situation?